# is there a way to duplicate a Frame or an Entry in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i tried to make a Entry in tkinter duplicated with for loops and while loops
if you don't understand me i want to make a bunch of Entry's with the same Variable like
`e = Entry(root).pack()` is there a way to do it or is it **impossible**?

Comment: Yes, you can make a whole list of entries if you like: `entries = [Entry(root).pack() for _ in range(10)]`. Is that all you want?

Comment: But how would you place it? if you .```place()``` it it just shows 1?

Comment: You can iterate over the list and call the `place` method on each element. Please show a concrete example of the code you want to automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have implemented this in the past is by creating a list ahead of my loop, then inside the loop you create the Entry as usual and add pack/grid it into your frame however you will, but then add your Entry to the list before you loop back again. That way you still have full access to each of the Entries but can dynamically populate your Frame.

This method works with any widget.

```
def demo(self):
    self.tk_str_entries = []                                 # tk.StringVars list
    self.tk_entries = []                                     # tk.Entry list
    max_range = 10                                           # How many Entrys to make

    self.tk_demo_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)               # tk.Frame to hold Entrys

    for _ in range(max_range):                               # loop thru your range
        tk_str = tk.StringVar()                              # - create local tk.StringVar
        entry = tk.Entry(self.tk_demo_frame, textvariable=tk_str) # - create entry, link it to local StringVar
        self.tk_str_entries.append(tk_str)                   # - append StringVar to the list
        self.tk_entries.append(entry)                        # - append Entry to the list
        entry.pack()
```

Comment: @PyCoder64 updated main answer with the code.
This is the baseline tho and you will still need some logic to determine which entry in the list you want to collect the data from and all, but over all this should be a good starting point for what youre looking for.

Comment: @PyCoder64 also i noticed from your original question something i ran into: sometimes we have the inclination is to chain everything together just because its possible, you create your widget and immediately pack it into it's frame on 1 line.
When setting a variable to the result of chained commands in python, the last one in the chain is the return.
While you created your Entry correctly, you immediately used that object to call .pack() which always returns None, so your e variable gets a value of None.
That is why the code above is able to store the Entry objects compared to your code.